# Check if filename includes %2F for file(image) upload

Tags: php

I am making a file(image) upload page.

I want to make the checking process if filename includes %2F.

This is the script for now :

```
$target_dir = "/home/ID/img/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if name is empty
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] == "") {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<div style='text-align:center;'><h2><br>Sorry, file already exists. <strong>Use other filename</strong></h2><h3>or<br><a href='https://img.sjang.xyz/". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). "' target='_blank'>Check the image with that filename</a></h3></div><span>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 20971520) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "ico"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Failed";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
```

For now, if the filename includes %2F, I cannot show up the image.
Is there a way to check if ["name"] includes %2F and make $uploadOk == 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **code** for checking the `%2F` in the filename:

```
if(strpos($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], '%2F') == true) {
   $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try strpos( ) as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

But remember, this function returns the substrings position, not TRUE. It does return FALSE if the substring is not found. So you may try:

```
if(strpos($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], '%2F') !== FALSE) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't paste the duplicate answer.

Comment: This is not a duplicate answer. The first answer says strpos( ) can return true, but according to documentation, it does not.

Comment: Hey dude it is the same condition if strpos() return true or return not false. Both situations are same.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but keep in mind that if a substring is the first occurrence, strpos( ) will return 0, in which case it will not evaluate to true.  I wanted to establish good practice for the OP.